# How to use findByType with a boolean value

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, webstorm

I am attempting to get a boolean value out of

```
    module.exports.getHospitalByEmergencyServices = async (req, res) => {
    var eServices = req.params.emergency_services
    var hospital = await Hospital.findByType(eServices).exec();
    res.status(200).json({data : hospital});
};
```

I am struggling to find the appropriate documentation that will allow me to get a boolean value from this. This set up works just fine with my string values but completely errors out from the boolean value. Any help that would point me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose does not have findbyType method. You can set yor own virtuals if you want. refer to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html

```js
var hospital = await Hospital.find("type":eServices) //use findOne if you want just one record.Assumed that Hospitals have a type field
```